# Unable to build files for Amazon Kinesis Video Streams using CPP Producer

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake, openssl

While trying to compile [amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp-repo](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp)  I am getting an error
`crypto\uplink-x86_64.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'`.
I do not understand this. I checked solutions online but I do not have any VS project. I am running all these commands just to compile the OpenSSL library. I tried running on x86 Native Tools Command Prompt as specified in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31595869/how-to-resolve-the-module-machine-type-x86-conflicts-with-target-machine-type) question. Still same error.
I am using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017.
Here are the steps I followed:

1: Clone the repo. Installed `cmake` and `pkg-config`.

2: I built the directory and navigated to it:

```
mkdir -p amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/build
cd amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp
```

3: Run the following command in Developer's command prompt for VS 2017:
`cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"`

Here is the error I am getting:

```
crypto\uplink-x86_64.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
Could Not Find C:\Users\amay\amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp\open-source\local\libopenssl\build\src\project_libopenssl\libcrypto-1_1-x64.*
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'link' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx86\x86\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\project_libopenssl.dir\build.make:130: build/src/project_libopenssl-stamp/project_libopenssl-build] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:94: CMakeFiles/project_libopenssl.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:102: all] Error 2
CMake Error at dependency/libkvscproducer/kvscproducer-src/CMake/Utilities.cmake:93 (message):
  CMake step for libopenssl failed: 2
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  dependency/libkvscproducer/kvscproducer-src/CMakeLists.txt:66 (build_dependency)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/amay/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Tried running with x64 Native Tools Command Prompt and it worked.