# Visual c++ machine type incompatibility

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, opencv3.0

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with external opencv libraries. When I try to run the code I am presented with this error:

`opencv_highgui300d.lib(window.obj) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86`

I have tried to change the target machine type from the properties manager of the project and the custom `opencv_debug` property sheets. Either way it says the selected machine type is incompatible. I have also looked around at solutions that worked for Visual Studio 2010 or lower but none worked for me.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849517/linking-problem-fatal-error-lnk1112-module-machine-type-x64-conflicts-with-t

Comment: I did but it just presented more incompatibility issues.